# How can I copy PDBs from additional include directories to lib output directory?

Tags: msbuild

I have a complex solution with many projects and many users adding new projects. The way we have our third party libraries set up, we need to copy the .pdb files for the 3p lib to live next to our lib that wraps it. E.g., if we are using LibFoo, we will have a project call OurLibFoo that wraps LibFoo, abstracts it, and sets up the dependency against it. Because Visual Studio will only look for .pdb files either with the final executable or with libraries it builds itself, it will only look in Path-to-OurLibFoo for LibFoo.pdb. So we have a custom build step that uses xcopy to copy LibFoo.pdb to Path-To-OurLibFoo. I'm trying to simplify and automate that process by setting up a custom target that will read AdditionalLibraryDirectory and copy all pdb files in each of those directories to $(OutDir). I can't seem to get it to work correctly, no doubt because I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something about how msbuild variables are structured. Here's some code that doesn't work:

```
<Target Name="CopyPdbs" AfterTargets="BeforeLib" DependsOnTargets="Lib" BeforeTargets="AfterLib">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Lib Include="@(ClCompile)"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Pdb Include="%(Lib.AdditionalLibraryDirectories)"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <PdbNames Include="@(Pdb->'%(rootdir)%(directory)*.pdb')"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <PdbNamesExplicit Include="@(PdbNames)"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="Copying files for falcon... @(PdbNamesExplicit)" Importance="high" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(PdbNamesExplicit)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" ContinueOnError="false" />        
  </Target>
```

This fails because Copy will not accept a path with wildcards and the wildcard in PdbNames never gets expanded. (It would probably fail for other reasons too, but I haven't gotten that far yet.)

How can I do this more succinctly and, most importantly, correctly?

Thanks!